# How can I account for bad data when checking values in an array?

Tags: javascript

I recently opened up a question on how to check for values in an arry that may or may not exist. There was an answer to the question but it seems not to account for all possibilites. Here's the data that I have:

Here for reference are the objects:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(wos.word))
VM6085:1 {"wordId":"tyyyyyy","wordIdentity":160,"ascii":116,"categoryId":1,"groupId":1,"lessonId":1,"ielts":null,"toefl":true,"toeic":null,"wordForms":[{"wordFormId":"qwqwqwqwq","wordFormIdentity":145,"ascii":113,"wordId":"tyyyyyy","primary":false,"posId":1,"sampleSentences":[],"synonyms":[],"wordDefinitions":[{"wordDefinitionId":142,"wordFormId":"qwqwqwqwq","text":"wrwrwrwrwr","ascii":119}],"pos":null,"version":"AAAAAAAADn0=","createdBy":2,"createdDate":"2016-05-03T13:23Z","modifiedBy":2,"modifiedDate":"2016-05-03T20:23Z"}],"lesson":null,"wordCategory":null,"wordGroup":null,"version":"AAAAAAAADf4=","createdBy":2,"createdDate":"2016-05-03T13:23Z","modifiedBy":2,"modifiedDate":"2016-05-03T20:23Z","current":true}
```

Same here but maybe easier to see:

console.log(JSON.stringify(wos.word))
VM6085:1 {"wordId":"tyyyyyy","wordIdentity":160,"ascii":116,"categoryId":1,"groupId":1,"lessonId":1,"ielts":null,"toefl":true,"toeic":null,"wordForms":[{"wordFormId":"qwqwqwqwq","wordFormIdentity":145,"ascii":113,"wordId":"tyyyyyy","primary":false,"posId":1,"sampleSentences":[],"synonyms":[],"wordDefinitions":[{"wordDefinitionId":142,"wordFormId":"qwqwqwqwq","text":"wrwrwrwrwr","ascii":119}],"pos":null,"version":"AAAAAAAADn0=","createdBy":2,"createdDate":"2016-05-03T13:23Z","modifiedBy":2,"modifiedDate":"2016-05-03T20:23Z"}],"lesson":null,"wordCategory":null,"wordGroup":null,"version":"AAAAAAAADf4=","createdBy":2,"createdDate":"2016-05-03T13:23Z","modifiedBy":2,"modifiedDate":"2016-05-03T20:23Z","current":true}

I am trying this code:

```
if (wos.word.wordForms && wos.word.wordForms[0].wordDefinitions && wos.word.wordForms[0].wordDefinitions[0].wordDefinitionId) {
    wos.wordDefinitionId = wos.word.wordForms[0].wordDefinitions[0].wordDefinitionId;
}
if (wos.word.wordForms && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0].synonymId){
    wos.synonymId = wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0].synonymId
}

// When I debug the code does not reach the next line. 

if (wos.word.wordForms && wos.word.wordForms[0].sampleSentences && wos.word.wordForms[0].sampleSentences[0].sampleSentenceId) {
    wos.sampleSentenceId = wos.word.wordForms[0].sampleSentences[0].sampleSentenceId
}
```

However when I debug the code does not reach the final "if"

Can someone help by telling me if there is something wrong with the way I am doing the check, something that is missing that would allow the code to exit without getting to the end when I debug in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: Always use opening and closing brackets in all your `if / else`  statement. Impossible to read this code.

Comment: There's actually only 6 lines of code so I think it's not too hard to read but I will add the brackets

Comment: It's not about the length of code. It could cause lot of problems if you miss that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms` will evaluate to true in your `if` statement, as it is defined and is an empty list:

```
if (wos.word.wordForms && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0].synonymId){
    ...
}
```

You can try it yourself: `if (wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms) { alert('Yes!'); }`

But right next to it, you try to access `wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0]`, which does not exist, hence the `TypeError: wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0] is undefined`. The same situation is with your `wos.word.wordForms[0].sampleSentences`

In order to fix this, check the length of the list as well:

```
if (wos.word.wordForms 
  && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms 
  && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms.length  // <-- check for element existence
  && wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0].synonymId) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much !

Comment: Can you also answer question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296133/how-can-i-check-if-a-variable-in-an-array-in-an-array-in-an-array-is-defined-and#37296133 which is related but which nobody could answer. Thanks

Comment: @SamanthaJ It's the same approach. What problem exactly do you encounter in that question, so that I know how can I help?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not executing beyond the first block because `wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0]` is undefined:

```
TypeError: wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Yeah but I have a check for that in the if statement:  wos.word.wordForms[0].synonyms so once that returns false then the rest of the if statement will not continue. So I don't see that could be the problem :-(